# GWTP Bootstrapper Implementation not found

Tags: java, gwt, bootstrapper, gwtp

I am using GWTP(1.2), GWT 2.5.1 for my project. I have all related jars of gwt, gwtp, guice, gin, etc.. in my classpath.

In my gwt xml module, I have defined following for bootstrap

```
  <!-- GWTP -->
    <inherits name='com.gwtplatform.mvp.MvpWithEntryPoint' />
    <set-configuration-property name="gwtp.bootstrapper"  
         value="com.example.client.gin.BootstrapperImpl"/> 

    <!-- Default GIN Module -->
    <set-configuration-property name="gin.ginjector.modules" 
                                value="com.example.client.gin.ClientModule" />
```

I have both BootstrapperImpl and ClientModule class inside proper folder structure (com->example->client->gin), but I get following error during GWT compilation:

```
 Computing all possible rebind results for 'com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.ApplicationController'
      Rebinding com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.ApplicationController
         Invoking generator com.gwtplatform.mvp.rebind.ApplicationControllerGenerator
            [ERROR] The type 'com.example.client.gin.BootstrapperImpl' was not found.
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are missing a `<source path='[...]'/>` entry in your .gwt.xml to include `com.example.client` as a GWT source folder